# I am getting a segfault only inside of linux using this function to accept integers for a BST

Tags: c

I've been using this function to accept user input into a BST/BSTs for a few programs. It compiles and runs without error using MinGW and the Compiler for Dev-C, however it throws a segmentation fault when compiled using gcc inside of linux. Any insight would be appreciated.

```
//Accepts user input and places it in the tree
node *getNumbers(struct node *t){
    char buffer[200];           //fgets buffer
    char delim[] = " \t\n";
    char* token;
    int n;

    printf("\nEnter a set of numbers for a tree:\n");

    //Reads from stdin to a buffer to parse for integers
    fgets(buffer, 200, stdin);
    token = strtok (buffer, delim);
    n = atoi(token);
    t = insertNode(t, n);
    while (token != NULL) {
        token = strtok(NULL,delim);
        n = atoi(token);
        t = insertNode(t, n);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: On second look the problem is most likely in your `insertNode` function. See: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Aha! Found it, turns out I had copied an older, malfunctioning version of insertNode. Thank you, man these segmentation faults can be tricky to track down.

Comment: You are missing some pretty important error checking from this code. If you removed it (for brevity) that's fine -- but if you put this code in production you're opening the door to future seg faults. Ex: you don't check fgets() return value, nor do you validate what you pump into your first call to token() and more importantly into `atoi()`. Beware.

Comment: Not in production or anything, just in the process of learning C. Could you point me in the direction of some more robust error checking?

Comment: So with strtol I could skip the business with tokenzing and atoi and just pull each integer in successive calls?